# Setup default font with C# for MS Word

Tags: c#

I want to set a default font style for my word document created using C#.
I'm new with C# so I don't have much knowledge what are the syntax for doing this.
Though I record a macro to know what code should I use but cannot convert it with C# code

This is the sample VBA Macro Code:

```
With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font
    .Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Size = 12
    .Bold = False
    .Italic = False
    .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    .etc....
End With
```

I hope someone can tell me what is the equivalent C# code of this. Tnx

Comment: Why do you want to use C#? Wouldnt it be better to just create a default template in word. Or if you want to do it in C# take a look at this article. [Creating Word 2007 Templates Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266219(office.12).aspx) Or just make a template using this article. [How to Create a Template in Word](http://www.ehow.com/how_2078655_create-template-word.html)

Comment: I'm using C# because I need to convert a raw document to new formated document where the data will be organized in a table, sections, header/footer etc. Using just a template will not output what I need. And I didn't find a solution from your link to create template. Well I'll review that link again later, thanks for your response.

Comment: After a whole night of sleep, I come up with the idea of using a template as what kyndigs suggested. Though it will not cover up all the things that I need, but it will save a lot of code. I'm going to use the template to my title page, table contents and others. Then for the body and rest will be handle by the C#. I see also the advantage of using template for a future changes in my header section. So thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
Word.Document normal_template = Application.NormalTemplate.OpenAsDocument();

normal_template.Range().Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
normal_template.Range().Font.Size = 16;
normal_template.Close(SaveChanges: true);
```

Comment: That is absolutely the **WRONG** way to do it. The **RIGHT** way is to modify the Normal Style, which is what the OP's VBA code demonstrates, but the change should be made to the template upon which the documents are to be based. More than that, though, since creating & modifying a template is a once-off exercise, it should be done manually (i.e., no code is needed).

Comment: I understand, but doing it programatically is necesary if it is to be done on multiple machines. I give my add-in to the customers, and they just install it and get the normal_template updated without any dificulties. Agree ?